# How to append some command output at the end of each line in a Vi file?

Tags: shell, unix, vim, awk, vi

Suppose I have a vi file as the following:

cat file1

```
abc 123 pqr
lmn 234 rst
jkl 100 mon
```

I want to take the 2nd field of each line (viz, in this case is 123, 234 and 100) and append it to the end of that same line. 
How will I do that?

The output should look like the following:

```
abc 123 pqr 123
lmn 234 rst 234
jkl 100 mon 100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk '{NF=NF+1; $NF=$2}1' file
abc 123 pqr 123
lmn 234 rst 234
jkl 100 mon 100
```

It increments the number of field in one and sets the last one as the 2nd. Then `1` is a true condition, which is evaluated as the default awk behaviour: `{print $0}`.

Or also

```
awk '{print $0, $2}' file
```

It prints the full line plus the second field.

Or even shorter, [thanks Håkon Hægland!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624505/how-to-append-some-command-output-at-the-end-of-each-line-in-a-vi-file/21624605?noredirect=1#comment32677309_21624605):

```
awk '{$(NF+1)=$2}1' file
```

Comment: I tried this: awk '{NF=NF+1; $NF=$3}1' bteq_files > bteq_files. But the file got emptied. Why is that? Without redirecting, I got the correct output on my prompt.

Comment: You cannot read from a file and redirect to the same one. Instead, use a temp file and then move it to the original: `awk '{NF=NF+1; $NF=$2}1' file > temp_file && mv temp_file file`

Comment: Also, what does the '1' after the closing curly brace do in this command?

Comment: @AjimBagwan The `1` tells `awk` to perform the default action, which is `{print $0}`.

Comment: Nice answer. Also, if the OP wants to do this while running vi, one can type `:%!awk '{ print $0, $2 }'` followed by the enter key, which will filter the entire buffer through that awk command.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick : Thanks Mark. Yours is working too. Isn't there some other way to do this without using 'awk'? I was thinking something like  using 'cat the line'+'a space-delimited cut to get the 2nd field + append it to the end of line'. But have no idea how to run or concat multiple commands from vi file.

Comment: @Ajim Bagwan, in a shell, you could use `cut -d ' ' -f 2` > tempfile to print only the second field, then `paste` to paste together the original contents with cut's output. But, running `:!cut -d ' ' -f 2` in `vi` would completely replace the buffer's contents, and the original contents wouldn't be available to use with the paste. Perhaps `vim` can run commands across multiple buffers; I don't know.

Comment: Yes, that could be a good option, @MarkPlotnick, but I prefer a stand alone `awk` that does everything. Also, thanks for the suggestion before: `:%!awk '{ print $0, $2 }'`. I did not know you can run external programs from vim!

Comment: @fedorqui, see `:help filter`.

Comment: @fedorqui I agree, `awk` is the best tool to use here. I mentioned `cut` and `paste` because a comment asked about using `cut`.

Comment: I was thinking if there's some way like 
:1,$s/$/`cut -d ' ' -f2`/g
where the output of inner cut command will replace the text that I want.

Answer (score 1):

You have many ways to do that in Vi(m). This is the simplest that comes to my mind:

```
:%norm 0f<space>yaw$p
```

Explanation:

- `:{range}norm command` executes normal mode `command` on each line in `{range}`
- `%` is a shortcut range meaning "all lines in the buffer" so we will execute what follows on every line in the buffer
- `0` puts the cursor on the first column on the current line (not strictly necessary but good practice)
- `f<space>` jumps the cursor on the first `<space>` after the cursor on the current line
- `yaw` yanks the word and the `<space>` under the cursor
- `$` jumps to the end of the line
- `p` pastes the previously yanked text

Comment: Could you please break down this command and explain what it is doing?

Comment: @romanil: Very neat! One more question: What if I want the cursor to jump on the second space after the current cursor position? What do I use instead of 0f?

Comment: `2f<pace>` is one way but I don't like to count chars and words, `f<space>;` is dumber and easier.

Answer (score -1):

prompt with mark, you can do it in vi

```
:%s/\( [^ ]*\)\(.*\)/\1\2\1/
```

Another way, Using sed

```
sed -r 's/( [^ ]*)(.*)/\1\2\1/' file
```

Comment: Wasn't the question targeted on vi?

Comment: Thanks for figuring out which regexp to use. This leads to a way the OP can do it completely in vim: type `:%s/\( [^ ]*\)\(.*\)/\1\2\1/`

Comment: @ LordT, is the reason you vote down? I have updated with vi solution.