# How to swap two fixed column values for each occurrence in vi shell?

Tags: shell, unix, vi

I have a file with data in the following format:
cat file1

```
a b c d e
e f g h i
p q r s t
```

I want the output to be in the following format:

```
a c b d e
e g f h i
p r q s t
```

What is the best way to do this swapping of two columns in vi or shell?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swap two columns - awk, sed, python, perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967776/swap-two-columns-awk-sed-python-perl)

Comment: Sorry. I tried searching for it. But couldn't find it. I was searching for vi and unix shell. Perhaps you guys should add the tags for it in that answer and also include the vi version of the answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk` for example:

```
$ awk '{a=$2; $2=$3; $3=a}1' file
a c b d e
e g f h i
p r q s t
```

You can make it more general with:

```
$ awk -v c1=FIRST_COL -v c2=SECOND_COL '{a=$c1; $c1=$c2; $c2=a}1' file
```

For example:

```
$ awk -v c1=2 -v c2=3 '{a=$c1; $c1=$c2; $c2=a}1' file
a b d c e
e f h g i
p q s r t
```

---

To use it from inside `vi`, use the following before the command:

```
:%!
```

So that the full command to execute is:

```
:%!awk '{a=$2; $2=$3; $3=a}1'
```

Comment: And in vi, the following works:
:%!awk '{a=$2; $2=$3; $3=a}1' 
Cool. Thanks.

Comment: To make it work in `vi` you just need to call it with `:%!`, [as Mark Plotnick said in your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624505/how-to-append-some-command-output-at-the-end-of-each-line-in-a-vi-file#comment32676522_21624605).

Comment: Yeah it works. Will accept the answer in next 4 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Inside vi you can do this command:

```
:%!awk '{c3=$3; $3=$2; $2=c3} 1'
```